# allocate memory to unknown type c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am doing a chess project with cpp.

My board is a metrix of pointer to Piece, and when I construct it I allocate memory to different type of pieces ( Rook, King, Bishop ...).

(for example: `this->_board[i][j] = new King()`)

I want to deep copy the board.
My Idea is to itterate through the board, and for every piece I will allocate new memory to the type of the piece.
What I tried:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < NUM_COLUMN; j++)
    {
        if (this->_board[i][j] != nullptr)
        {
            this->_board[i][j] = new typeid(*(other->_board[i][j]));
        }
    }
}
```

**What command can I use instead of** `typeid(*(other->_board[i][j]))`, that will return a (King) type  (for example), and I will be able to allocate memory for it?

thank you.

Comment: Also consider using `std::unique_ptr` instead of raw pointers.

Comment: don't use manual memory management. Use smart pointers. Don't use raw C arrays. Use `std::vector` or `std::array`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use virtual function. For example,

```
class Piece
{
public:
    virtual Piece* clone() = 0;
};

class King : public Piece
{
public:
    virtual Piece* clone()
    {
        return new King(*this);
    }
};
```

and then deep copy with `other->_board[i][j]->clone()`.